# Change Wordpress Featured Image on Hover

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple featured images assigned to a custom post type in wordpress. I'm trying to get it so that featured image 1 (portfolio-title-image) changes to featured image 2 (portfolio-hover-image) on hover. Here's my php in my wordpress custom post pages where the featured images come from. I've tried various jquery approaches but my knowledge isn't great enough to come up with a solution.

```php
<div class="portfolio-item">

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

<?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) { kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'portfolio-title-image', 'portfolio' );}?></a>

<?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) { kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'portfolio-hover-image', 'portfolio' );}?></a>

</div>
```

Comment: this question is highly specific to your plugin, kdMultipleFeaturedImages. You should ask this on their support forum, since most of us here have no clue what it is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS approach.

Markup:

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="cont">

      <div class="unhover_img">
        <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) { kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'portfolio-title-image', 'portfolio' );}?>
      </div>

      <div class="hover_img">
        <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) { kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'portfolio-hover-image', 'portfolio' );}?>
      </div>

    </a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover_img {
  display: none
}
.cont:hover .unhover_img{
  display: none;
}
.cont:hover .hover_img {
  display: block;
}
```